# React router chunk bundle not fetched when visited that route

Tags: django, reactjs, webpack

I want to load the bundle when the route url is visited. My server is django `localhost:8000`. My webpack splits up the bundle.

[image: console text]

**My router component:**

```html
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import App from '../app';
//import CollegeList from '../apps/college/CollegeList';
import CollegeDetail from '../apps/college/CollegeDetail';
import CourseList from '../apps/course/CourseList';
import CourseDetail from '../apps/course/CourseDetail';
import UniversityList from '../apps/university/UniversityList';
import UniversityDetail from '../apps/university/UniversityDetail';
import AdmissionList from '../apps/admission/AdmissionList';
import AdmissionDetail from '../apps/admission/AdmissionDetail';
import CareerList from '../apps/career/CareerList';
import CareerDetail from '../apps/career/CareerDetail';
import EventList from '../apps/event/EventList';
import EventDetail from '../apps/event/EventDetail';
import NewsList from '../apps/news/NewsList';
import NewsDetail from '../apps/news/NewsDetail';
import ScholarshipList from '../apps/scholarship/ScholarshipList';
import ScholarshipDetail from '../apps/scholarship/ScholarshipDetail';
import VacancyList from '../apps/vacancy/VacancyList';
import VacancyDetail from '../apps/vacancy/VacancyDetail';
import RankList from '../apps/rank/RankList';
import RankDetail from '../apps/rank/RankDetail';
import FacultyCourseList from '../apps/faculty/FacultyCourseList';
import LoginForm from '../apps/users/components/LoginForm';
import SignUpForm from '../apps/users/components/SignUpForm';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import Footer from '../components/Footer';
import LoadingComponent from '../components/LoadingComponent.js';


function loadRoute(cb) {
    return module => {console.log(module);cb(null, module.default)};
}

class AppRoute extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <LoadingComponent/>
                    <Header />
                    <Route exact path='/' component={App}/>
                    <Route exact path='/colleges' getComponent={(location, cb) => {
                        System.import('../apps/college/CollegeList')
                            .then(loadRoute(cb))
                            .catch((error) => {console.log('error')});
                    }}/>
                    <Route path='/colleges/:slug' component={CollegeDetail}/>
                    <Route exact path='/courses' component={CourseList}/>
                    <Route path='/courses/:slug' component={CourseDetail}/>
                    <Route exact path='/universities' component={UniversityList}/>
                    <Route path='/universities/:slug' component={UniversityDetail}/>
                    <Route exact path='/admissions' component={AdmissionList}/>
                    <Route path='/admissions/:slug' component={AdmissionDetail}/>
                    <Route exact path='/careers' component={CareerList}/>
                    <Route path='/careers/:slug' component={CareerDetail}/>
                    <Route exact path='/events' component={EventList}/>
                    <Route path='/events/:slug' component={EventDetail}/>
                    <Route exact path='/news' component={NewsList}/>
                    <Route path='/news/:slug' component={NewsDetail}/>
                    <Route exact path='/scholarships' component={ScholarshipList}/>
                    <Route path='/scholarships/:slug' component={ScholarshipDetail}/>
                    <Route exact path='/vacancies' component={VacancyList}/>
                    <Route path='/vacancies/:slug' component={VacancyDetail}/>
                    <Route exact path='/ranks' component={RankList}/>
                    <Route path='/ranks/:slug' component={RankDetail}/>
                    <Route exact path='/faculties' component={FacultyCourseList}/>
                    <Route path='/login' component={LoginForm}/>
                    <Route path='/signup' component={SignUpForm}/>
                    <br/>
                    <Footer />
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}

export default AppRoute
```

According to documentation this should lazy-load my bundle when that route is visited. When I visit the url bundle is not fetch and nothing loads up.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ANqU.png)

Thanks.

Comment: what error do you see on the console?

Comment: There isn't any error, webpack creates bundle but when the url is visited it only shows white screen as I have posted, no errors on `console.log()`. No request in Network tab of devtool also.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `System.import` because it is deprecated in favor of `import()`. However, you are not passing the component to your `loadRoute` callback.

```
.then(module => loadRoute(cb, module))
```

I don't think it would work in the way you implemented

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to implement `import()`.

Comment: Following this guide 
[webpack async code-spliting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-async/) 
I have used require.ensure in my router as 

`<Route exact path='/colleges' 
   getComponent={(nextState, cb) => {
                        require.ensure([], 
                        require => cb(null, 
                        require('../apps/college/CollegeList').default))
                    }}/>`
but I still won't fetch the bundle, I am not sure if getComponent is being called

Answer (score 0):

getComponent won't work in react-router-dom. To load component async we have to use asyncComponent. Detail explanation in [code-splitting-react-router-dom](https://hackernoon.com/code-splitting-for-react-router-with-webpack-and-hmr-bb509968e86f)